# Sliding text button: how to make it sliding in all direction with CSS3

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have made a sliding text button that slides upward when hovered. Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/kEQq4/

How to make it sliding not only upward, but also downward, leftward or rightward?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
<style> 
a{
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align: center;
  display:block; /* important */
}

.blue-btn, .first-link{
  -webkit-transition: 1.8s;
  -moz-transition: 1.8s;
  -ms-transition: 1.8s;
  transition: 1.8s;     
}

.blue-btn{
  height: 64px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 64px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3b5998;
}

.blue-btn:hover{
   background-color: #ff0000;
}

.first-link{
  margin-top: 0;   
}

.blue-btn:hover .first-link{
  margin-top: -64px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="blue-btn">
      <a class="first-link" href="#"> First Text </a>
      <a href="#"> Second Text </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `I have made`... hum hum... Funny somebody else did the same code, see [here](http://codepen.io/RichardBray/pen/julhw).

Answer (score 0):

I've never used css before so I can't verify that you're doing this the right way (feels more like a hack to me) , however, using your code as the base, I modified it so that it slides to the left.

Take a look :) http://jsfiddle.net/kEQq4/20/

```
a{
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align: center;
  display:block; /* important */
}

.blue-btn, .first-link{
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;     
}

.blue-btn, .second-link{
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;     
}

.blue-btn{
  height: 64px;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 64px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3b5998;
}

.blue-btn:hover{
   background-color: #ff0000;
}

.first-link{
  margin-top: 0px;   
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.second-link{
    margin-top: -64px;
    margin-left: 300px;
}

.blue-btn:hover .first-link{
    margin-left: -300px;
}
.blue-btn:hover .second-link{
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```